# How to act on rectangles beyond the end-of-line?

Tags: text-editing, vim-emulation, rectangle

Here's what Vim's documentation has to say about it:

> Virtual editing means that the cursor can be positioned where there is
>           no actual character.  This can be halfway into a tab or beyond the end
>           of the line.  Useful for selecting a rectangle in Visual mode and
>           editing a table.

I'd preferably like to see this implemented as a minor mode or a built in setting.

Comment: Do you want this for selecting a rectangle? If that's the case it's the default in current development version.

Comment: No, I'm thinking more like yanking/replacing rectangles. I do use the rectangle mark mode and while it is a nice feature it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Indeed, for yanking/replacing rectangles, it'd be a natural companion to the existing functionality in rectangle-mark-mode.  Not sure what the UI should be, tho.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Stefan. This feature would be most useful when dealing with rectangles, so perhaps while in rectangle mark mode a command could toggle a virtual edit type of mode. Right now in rectangle mark mode, the point looks like it's in a virtual edit mode: it can move past the end of a line with `C-f`. But when you yank a rectangle after doing this, the rectangle appears at the mark instead of the point. If it appeared at the point, that would solve this issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `extend-rectangle-to-end` function in the `rectangle-utils` package is what you want. It's on `melpa`.

It inserts spaces to make the current rectangle selection extend to cover the longest line in the region.

To get this behaviour, I've got  this in my init.el. `C-x r e` is not bound to anything else in vanilla emacs

```
(require 'rectangle-utils)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x r e") 'extend-rectangle-to-end)
```

Comment: To clarify, with this package, you select the region, then do `M-x extend-rectangle-to-end` and then `C-x r M-w` or `C-x r k`.

Answer (score 19):

Another answer: use **`M-x picture-mode`**.  You can kill or copy rectangles through the middle of tab chars etc., send them to registers, etc.

Comment: One advantage of using this method is that you can control exactly how wide you want your rectangle selection to be. If I have line 1 with 30 chars and line 2 with 5 chars, I can choose the rectangle to be 15 chars wide and 2 lines tall; can't do that with `extend-rectangle-to-end` as the rectangle selection with that will always be 30x2.

Comment: `picture-mode` is old and little-known.  Among other little-known features it has: exiting (`C-c C-c`) removes trailing whitespace.

Comment: That's brilliant, Drew!  Question: are there any reason *not* to advice `rectangle-minor-mode` to be "wrapped" in `picture-mode`? (advice since I don't see any hooks in the source of `rectangle-minor-mode`).

Comment: Here's my advice, btw.  It doesn't strip whitespace since that's kind of uncalled for here:
`(defun rectangle-mark-mode-wrapped-in-picture-mode (orig-fun &rest args)
  (if rectangle-mark-mode (picture-mode)
    (and (eq major-mode 'picture-mode) (picture-mode-exit t))))`

`(advice-add 'rectangle-mark-mode :around
            #'rectangle-mark-mode-wrapped-in-picture-mode)`